# User is not getting sign out firebase android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

User is not getting sign out Firebase android. When i press logout button it does not sign out.

Code is here:-

```
btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            logOut();



        }
    });

private void logOut() {

    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

}
```

Logs are:

> 02-13 23:54:19.654 3073-3073/com.example.imran.blooddonors I/View: Touch down dispatch to android.widget.Button{42d3afa0 VFED..C. ........ 120,594-600,690 #7f08002b app:id/btnAdminPanelLogout}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=218.52982, y[0]=88.352844, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=202325584, downTime=202325584, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 }
>   02-13 23:54:19.704 3073-3073/com.example.imran.blooddonors I/View: Touch up dispatch to android.widget.Button{42d3afa0 VFED..C. ...P.... 120,594-600,690 #7f08002b app:id/btnAdminPanelLogout}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=219.69275, y[0]=90.68005, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=202325635, downTime=202325584, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 }
>   02-13 23:54:19.706 3073-3073/com.example.imran.blooddonors D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event.
>   02-13 23:54:19.706 3073-3073/com.example.imran.blooddonors D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event.

Comment: try to use a service...

Comment: how did u know it is not signing out? By using the code above the authenticated user will be signed out of the app and won't be the current user. But you still need to take him to the specific activity

Comment: before it was working correctly and after sign out goes to login activity but not now

Comment: now what does it do?

Comment: it stays on same activity

Comment: i have to go manually??ok

Comment: @ImranAnwar check the answer to understand

Comment: Thanks now its working...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside this method:

```
private void logOut() {
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(i);

}
```

In the above the user will be signed out and then he will go to the LoginActivity.

Then inside your LoginActivity, you can check if there is a user logged in or no try this:

```
 FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

 if(user!=null){

  Log.i("a user is logged in: ",user);
 }
  else{
       Log.i("Username", "there is no user");
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{       
     FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();             
     Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                      
     MaterialPageRoute(builder: ((context) => MainPage())));
},
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.